# Remove all Empty's Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, fork, case

Consider the following type to represent trees:

```
data Tree a =Empty
            |Leaf a
            |Fork (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

I need help defining the function `clean :: Tree a -> Tree a` that removes all Empty's from a non-Empty tree. The function should return Empty when there is no element in the tree.

Note: A possibile tree is `Fork Empty Empty`

Here is what I have tried so far but I do not know if it is working for the above case:

```
clean :: Tree a -> Tree a
clean Leaf x = Leaf x
clean Fork Empty r = r  
clean Fork l Empty = r  
clean Fork l r =  aux l r --If both left and right are empty, I can't fork.


aux :: Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree a
aux l r = if (clean l)==Empty && (clean r)==Empty
          then Empty  else Fork (clean l) (clean r)  --I am not sure about this case?
```

Should I include the case clean Fork Empty Empty = Empty ?
This does not make much sense as I want to remove the whole Fork and not put an Empty there

Comment: You say that you don't know if your implementation works for the given case - you haven't tested it? Also I'd suggest to specify in more detail what you actually want. In particular, you want to replace `Empty`s with something else? Or update the structure of a tree? If so, how exactly?

Comment: @PetrPudlák I want update the structure of a tree by removing all Empty's

Comment: Do you mean `|Fork (Tree a) (Tree a)`?

Comment: @TomEllis Of course. Sorry for the typo. I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work (I can't try it right now):

```
clean :: Tree a -> Tree a
clean (Fork l r) = f (clean l) (clean r) where
   f Empty r = r
   f l Empty = l
   f l r = Fork l r
clean x = x
```